# timeseries via json in c3 line chart

Tags: php, d3.js, c3.js

I use d3/c3 library to create a chart with two lines representing timeseries: yr0 and yr0 on the y-axis, x is the x-axis data.
The lines are fed by a Json feed which I generate in PHP.
However the format of the feed is not correct. What do I need to change in the PHP script to make it work?

```
$data = array();


     for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
         $data[]= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
     }


 echo json_encode(array_values($data));
```

JSON result:

```
[{"wk":"1","wk51":"18","wk52":"27","wk1":"52","wk2":"73","wk3":"93","wk4":"81","wk5":"69","wk6":"76","wk7":"87","wk8":"81","wk9":"82","wk10":"102","wk11":"84","wk12":"66"},{"wk":"1","wk51":"133","wk52":"121","wk1":"38","wk2":"51","wk3":"66","wk4":"58","wk5":"46","wk6":"81","wk7":"74","wk8":"69","wk9":"74","wk10":"126","wk11":"116","wk12":"90"},{"wk":"1","wk51":"70","wk52":"68","wk1":"127","wk2":"136","wk3":"204","wk4":"199","wk5":"196","wk6":"208","wk7":"206","wk8":"206","wk9":"213","wk10":"213","wk11":"217","wk12":"226"},{"wk":"1","wk51":"78","wk52":"86","wk1":"79","wk2":"122","wk3":"130","wk4":"137","wk5":"161","wk6":"171","wk7":"149","wk8":"137","wk9":"136","wk10":"148","wk11":"164","wk12":"179"},{"wk":"1","wk51":null,"wk52":null,"wk1":"85","wk2":"80","wk3":"87","wk4":"86","wk5":"92","wk6":"94","wk7":"101","wk8":"106","wk9":"133","wk10":"136","wk11":"111","wk12":"100"}]
```

Javascript

```
var chart = c3.generate({bindto:"#chart_yr",data:{url:"/snowdepth/get_snowdepth2.php?res_id=<?php echo $res_id; ?>&his=1&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",mimeType:"json",types:{yr0:"area-spline",yr1:"area-spline"},keys:{x:"x",value:["yr0","yr1"]},axes:{yr0:"y",yr1:"y"},names:{yr0:"2018",yr1:"2019"}},color:{pattern:["#ff7f0e","#FF3D0D"]},
      grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [
                {value: 0, text: '0-line'}
            ]
        }
    },axis:{x:{type:"category"},y:{max:300,min:0,label:"snowdepth in cm"},y2:{max:10,min:-10,label:"temperature in degrees Celcius",show:!0}}});
```

Comment: Dont build JSON String manually, yours is not valid JSON. Build an array or object and then use `json_encode()` to make the JSONString

Comment: made the changes but the structure makes it more difficult to handle in the chart. I have no identifier for year anymore

Comment: You have to build the data in the format you want the JSON to look like